# Jquery Colorbox not showing after close when hosted on control in UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, colorbox

So I have a Colorbox setup for the document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnMyButton').colorbox({
        href: "./Modals/MyModal.aspx",
        iframe: true,
        height: 450,
        width: 550,
        opacity: .60,
        overlayClose: false,
        escKey: false,
        onClosed: function () {
            var mypage = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            mypage._doPostBack('upGrid', '');
        }
    });
});
```

On close of the colorbox I do a postback to my update panel (upGrid).  In MyModal I have a button that closes the Colorbox as such:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); return false;" CssClass="button cancel" />
```

The update panel contains a grid and the colorbox leads a user to an upload page.  If they succesfully upload a file the program parses the data to fill in the grid.  So when the OnClosed of the colorbox is called the grid should be updated.

If the user clicks btnMyButton and proceeds to click btnCancel on the Modal they are unable to click btnMyButton again to have the colorbox load the Modal again.  If I move btnMyButton outside of the update panel it functions fine, but I wanted btnMyButton inside the update panel to handle hiding/showing of it depending on if the user has already uploaded a file they shouldn't see it.

Has anyone ran into/solved any issues with colorbox not redisplaying after close inside an ASP.NET update panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

> It is also called after every partial postback. It basically functions
>   as a combination of Application.Init and
>   PageRequestManager.EndRequest.

```
function pageLoad()
{
   $('#btnMyButton').colorbox({
        href: "./Modals/MyModal.aspx",
        iframe: true,
        height: 450,
        width: 550,
        opacity: .60,
        overlayClose: false,
        escKey: false,
        onClosed: function () {
            var mypage = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            mypage._doPostBack('upGrid', '');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't believe it is an issue of when/where to postback for the update panel.  It is more of an issue that I cannot get the colorbox to function a second time if the update panel has received a postback.

Comment: This seems to work, just a bit more testing and it is a done deal.